# Schematic Editor - Library files

Tags: pcb, schematics

I am using Eagle5.11 to prepare schematic diagram. I need the .lbr file for 
[image][image]

*Breakaway-Male Header,CAT9532 SOIC 28 pin package*..

So where can i find a bulk of .lbr files for these small but necessary components?

What other .lbr's you would suggest for a guy preparing schematics for his projects that includes things like interfacing pic mcu(16f/32mx) with driver ic's(uln2003) and lots of sensors?

I got one from *sparkfun* but that doesnt contain what I am looking for

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The default libraries have most of these devices already available.  Check ref-packages.lbr for footprints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The microbuilder library http://www.microbuilder.eu/Projects/EagleFootprintLibrary.aspx is pretty good and is maintained by the all around nice guy Kevin Townsend.
There is also the adafruit library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Eagle-Library

That said, it would probably take no more than 5 minutes to draw that 100 mil header. In my experience Eagle footprints, even the standard ones, are of varying quality and it pays to learn to draw your own.